# Number of bounded non-negative integral solutions

Tags: combinatorics

What is the number of solutions of -

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \dots + x_n = k$

$(1)$ When all the $x_i$ are between $0$ and $r$.

$(2)$ What if the order of the $x_i$ doesn't matter?

I have doubts about the solution to the first part being the multinomial coefficient. For example, n=3, k=3, r=2. We get (1,1,1) and the 6 permutations of (0,1,2). So the total is 7. I don't think any multinomial coefficient will give 7.

EDIT: This question was for a video I was making on hypercubes. If you're interested, check it out :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KuXnrg1YpiY

Comment: There is no specific way to deal unless order is concerned.

Comment: @Fabian I don't think this is a homework problem because there is no general solution for this.

Comment: @JaideepKhare: what do you mean that there is no solution to this???

Comment: @Fabian There is no solution if there order is not taken into account (In general for $n$ and $k$), if order is important, then it is stars and bars problem, I will like to see if you have any general solution for this.

Comment: @Fabian - I assure you, this is not a homework question. I am too old for that ;)

Comment: @JaideepKhare - stars and bars don't work because the $x_i$ are bounded above.

Comment: @RohitPandey I said the same `(if order is important, then it is stars and bars problem)`

Comment: @JaideepKhare - if order is important and $x_i$ can be arbitrarily large integers, I can imagine how to use stars and bars but not when they can't be more than $r$.

Comment: @RohitPandey You can use Multinomial Theorem then.Do you know that?Also, is my edit okay for your question?

Comment: Yes, the edit is fine. Multinomial sounds good for the first part. Now the second.

Comment: I have no idea for that.(Probably there doesn't exist any)

Comment: For sure it exists. Let me give an answer.

Comment: @Fabian - eagerly waiting :)

Comment: Do it by stars and bars and just subtract the ones that have terms over r.

Comment: @Fleablood - but in stars and bars, the order of the $x_i$ matters no? For example, (1,0,0) and (0,1,0) will be counted twice while I want to count it once.

Comment: Then you count use exclusion to remove the duplicates. Definately doable albeit it tedious.  It's a bit absurd to assume it is impossible.

Comment: Guys, I have doubts about the first part being multinomial. For example, n=3, k=3, r=2. We get (1,1,1) and the 6 permutations of (0,1,2). So the total is 7. I don't think any multinomial coefficient will give 7.

Comment: It would improve your Question to add the small example you've presented in the above Comment to the body of the Question itself.  If you do not wish to do it yourself, I would volunteer to do so.

Comment: @hardmath - Good suggestion. Added to the question.

Answer (score 2):

- If the **order does not matter**, it is a [money changing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem) with coins $\{0,\dots,r\}$. We have the generating function
  $$\sum_{k,n\geq 0} p(k,n,r) x^k y^n = \frac{1}{(1-y)(1-yx)(1-yx^2)\cdots(1-y x^r)} = \prod_{j=0}^r (1-yx^j)^{-1}. $$
  You can obtain the values of $p(k,n,r)$ by taking the appropriate number of derivatives, i.e.,
  $$p(k,n,r) =\frac{1}{k! \,n!} \frac{\partial^k}{\partial x^k} \frac{\partial^n}{\partial y^n} \prod_{j=0}^r (1-yx^j)^{-1} \Big|_{x,y=0}$$
- If the **order matters**, we can obtain $p(k,n,r)$ by the coefficient of $x^k$ in
  $$ \left(\sum_{i=0}^r x^i \right)^n =\left(\frac{1-x^{r+1}}{1-x} \right)^n $$
  i.e. the generating function in this case is given by
  $$ \sum_{k}p(k,n,r) x^k  = \left(\frac{1-x^{r+1}}{1-x} \right)^n$$
  and we have
  $$p(k,n,r) = \frac{1}{k!}\frac{\partial^k}{\partial x^k} \left(\frac{1-x^{r+1}}{1-x} \right)^n \Big|_{x=0}.$$

Comment: For the first part, I'm actually not quite sure its multinomial anymore. For example, n=3, k=3, r=2. We get (1,1,1) and the 6 permutations of (0,1,2). So the total is 7. I don't think any multinomial coefficient will give 7. For the second part, let me study your solution.

Comment: @RohitPandey: fixed it. Please note the new solution.

Answer (score 2):

(1) When order of the summands matters, you are asking for the (weak) [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of $k$ in $n$ parts with restricted parts at most $r$, i.e from $\{0,\ldots,r\}$.

The binomial formula (stars-and-bars) is correct when $r$ (the bound on largest part) is omitted or sufficiently large as not to matter.

When $r$ is small enough to restrict the solutions, the resulting problem has been referred to in the literature as "compositions inside a rectangle".  See for example:

> B. E. Sagan, "Compositions inside a rectangle and unimodality", **J. Algebraic Combin. 29** (2009), 405–411.

A discussion of these is given by the [online paper](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL16/Eger/eger6.pdf) (end of Section 6.2)

> S. Eger, "Restricted Weighted Integer Compositions and Extended Binomial Coefficients", **Journal of Integer Sequences, Vol. 16** (2013)

There was [an earlier Question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21645/restricted-compositions) that also addressed these "restricted compositions". The OP there accepted a self-posted Answer pointing to [this paper](http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/14-5/abramson.pdf) by M. Abramson, which appears to have been published as:

> M. Abramson, "Restricted combinations and compositions", **Fibonacci Q.** (1976), 439–452

(2) You are asking, when order *does not* matter, for the [integer partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of $k$ with at most $n$ parts and largest part at most $r$.  A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646705/counting-integer-partitions-of-n-into-exactly-k-distinct-parts-size-at-most-m) asks also that the summands all be distinct, and there is a simple way to convert a problem of that form into the one described here (and conversely).  Notation for such countings vary among authors.

Counting the number of such solutions is not especially simple, although it yields readily to recursive solution/dynamic programming methods for modest values of $k$.

I've often turned to [an online calculator](http://www.se16.info/js/partitions.htm) (written in Java, by Henry Bottomley) for such modest computations, but running Java programs in modern browsers is no longer an easy task (due to security concerns [about NPAPI](https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml), the interface Java uses in browsers).

Many software packages address the problem of *counting* integer partitions through (brute force) *listing* of all possible solutions.  In a sense the latter is easier algorithmically, because we cannot expect to improve much in the output of a long list of solutions.  A recently updated broad survey of capabilities ("Software for enumerative and analytic combinatorics") by [Andrew MacFie (2013/2016)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.02683.pdf) describes "the capabilities that the packages offer as well as some of the algorithms used, and provide[s] links to original documentation."

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful.