# Distributing objects into different boxes such that number of objects are distinct.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

In how many ways I can distribute $n$ objects in $t$ boxes, $x_i$ objects in each box, such that $\sum_i x_{i}=n$ and $x_{i}\neq x_{j}$?

I've taken the case of 5 objects with 2 boxes. Firstly, I filled both boxes with the same elements (1,1) or (2,2) then I filled the remaining ones as (0,3) and (0,1) respectively so that the cases are (1,4) and (2,3) but I am not able to generalize the condition.

Comment: What is $x_i{}$?

Comment: $x_{i}$ is a positive integer.

Comment: What is $x_i$ in the context of **this problem**?

Comment: It does not make sense to say $x_i$ objects in each box if you want a different number of objects in each box.  It would be better to say $x_i$ objects in the $i$th box, where $x_i \neq x_j$ for each $i, j$ satisfying $1 \leq i, j \leq t$.  You should also edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Please have a look.

Comment: What you are looking for is the number of [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of $n$ with $t$ distinct parts. The solution is found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646705/counting-integer-partitions-of-n-into-exactly-k-distinct-parts-size-at-most-m).